# Nagios can't send notifications

Tags: notifications, nagios

I'm developing an automation tool for managing nagios (nagiosql is not sufficient enough for me).

When I am doing a integration test with nagios, something weird happens.

Here is the situation:

1. Nagios Configuration

   ```
   # grep log_notification /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
   log_notifications=1

   #grep enable_notifications /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
   enable_notifications=1
   ```
2. I created a sample contact, host, service, all without using templates

   ```
   define contact { 
       contact_name    jone.doe
       host_notifications_enabled  1
       service_notifications_enabled   1
       host_notification_period    7x24
       service_notification_period 7x24
       host_notification_options   d,u,r,f,s,n
       service_notification_options    w,u,c,r,f,s,n
       email   john.doe@xx.com
       host_notification_commands  notify_service_by_state
       service_notification_commands   notify_service_by_state
   }

   define host{
       host_name   localhost
       address localhost
       max_check_attempts  1
       check_period    7x24
       active_checks_enabled   1
       passive_checks_enabled  0
       check_command   check_host_alive
   }

   define service{
       host_name   localhost
       service_description check_the_process_count_of_the_local_machine
       check_command   check_local_procs!10!20!RSZDT
       max_check_attempts  3
       check_interval  3
       retry_interval  1
       notification_interval   3
       check_period    7x24
       notification_period 7x24
       notifications_enabled   1
       contacts   john.doe
   }
   ```
3. Hereby are some additional configuration file:

   ```
   define timeperiod{
       timeperiod_name 7x24
       alias   7x24
       monday  00:00-24:00
       tuesday 00:00-24:00
       wednesday   00:00-24:00
       thursday    00:00-24:00
       friday  00:00-24:00
       saturday    00:00-24:00
       sunday  00:00-24:00
   }

   define command { 
       command_name    check_local_procs
       command_line    $USER1$/check_procs -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -s $ARG3$
   }

   define command { 
       command_name    notify_service_by_state
       command_line    /usr/local/nagios/etc/scripts/notify.py "$SERVICESTATE$" "$CONTACTEMAIL$" "$CONTACTADDRESS1$" "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$" "$HOSTALIAS$" "$SERVICEDESC$" "$HOSTADDRESS$" "$SERVICEOUTPUT$" "$LONGDATETIME$"
   }

   define command { 
       command_name    check_host_alive
       command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
   }
   ```
4. and this is the `notify.py` source code, all packages installed.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   #coding:utf-8
   import codecs
   import sys
   import urllib
   import commands

   import smtplib
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText
   from email.header import Header

   import time

   fi = codecs.open('/data/appdatas/logs/message.log', 'a' , encoding='utf-8')
   fi.write("=======Begin Log\n");
   fi.write("Notify\n");
   fi.write(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + "\n");
   fi.write(sys.argv[1]+ "\n");
   fi.write("End Log=========\n");
   fi.close()
   ```

   To simplify the test process, I had `chmod +777` to the `log_file`.

   And `chmod +x notify.py`. And I've tested to execute the python script in the terminal, and there are logs in the log file.
5. As you can see the `check_local_proc` command. This command will return a code 2 as it executed.

In the `nagios.log` file, I have see these logs:

```
[1449588806] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;check_the_process_count_of_the_local_machine;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;PROCS CRITICAL: 423 processes with STATE = RSZDT
[1449588866] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;check_the_process_count_of_the_local_machine;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;PROCS CRITICAL: 423 processes with STATE = RSZDT
[1449588926] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;check_the_process_count_of_the_local_machine;CRITICAL;HARD;3;PROCS CRITICAL: 423 processes with STATE = RSZDT
```

As you can see from the log, this service is checked every 1 minute.

But there's no log in the message.log file (no execution of the notify.py).

Comment: When viewing the service on nagios web page for 'View Notification For This Service'. Got a red alert: **No notifications have been recorded for this service in the current log file**

Comment: Additional Information: in the nagios web page, when viewing _service information_ there's a link on the right: **Send custom service notification**. Using that link I can send notifications and there're data in the log file. So no thing wrong with the command configuration. Still investigation needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know why I cann't sent any notification.
Because I wrongly configured contact's configuration.
According to the official document: [Nagios Object Definitions](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html), the field `host_notification_options [d,u,r,f,s,n]`, `service_notification_options  [w,u,c,r,f,s,n]`; the option `n` means the contact will **not** receive any notifications.